# Linear Fractional Transformations

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $p(x)= \pi A_\alpha \pi^{-1}(x) = y$, where $$A_\alpha =
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha \\
\sin \alpha &  \cos \alpha\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ 
and $\pi:S\to C=\{z=x_1+ix_2\}\cup\infty$.

Show that $y = p(x)$ is a linear fractional transformation. I am a little confused on how to start this problem.

Comment: What is the function $\pi$?

Comment: Im so sorry I forgot to add that. $\pi : S ----> C$ = { z= x_{1} + i x_2} $\bigcup$ $\infty$

Comment: Should we assume $\pi$ is also a lft? If so, then all you need is that inverses of and products of lft's are lft's...

Comment: It is not stated whether or not $\pi$ is a lft or not. I think that may be the reson I am confused.

Comment: Do you have properties of [Schwarzian derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzian_derivative) at your disposal?

Comment: I think, from my understanding, is that I am suppossed to show that a LFT is induced by rotations of the circle. This question is so confusing.

Comment: @ Anon. I just read about the Schwarzian derv's. That is a useful trick or property. However, looking at the matrix, how would I show that the derivative of that is 0? Also, once I had this obtained, then would that show that p(x) = y is also 0 then, therefore it would be a LFT?

Comment: Marge, please tell a bit more. Is $S$, perhaps, the Riemann Sphere and $\pi$ the stereographic projection? This doesn't quite make sense given that $A$ looks like a 2D-rotation, but, pray, tell us what $S$ is? The reason I ask is that it is a standard exercise to show that rotations of the Riemann Sphere correspond to fractional linear transformations of the extended plane.

Comment: If you weren't familiar with SDs before now it would be a bad idea to put them in your homework. But they are indeed useful with their properties at your disposal (which themselves would either take hellish algebra or a high-concept view of where $S$ originally comes from - namely the local distortion of cross ratio under flow). I haven't looked at it fully but $S(p)=0$ would indeed imply $p$ is a LFT, and that might be possible to prove with $S$'s inversion and composition properties. (But you should probably do your homework separately first! Also, don't put a space after '@'; doesn't work.)

Comment: @Jyrki: Typically when I see a matrix juxtaposed with a complex variable in the context of Mobius transformations it's supposed to be the corresponding LFT, but your interpretation of a 2D rotation (along with $\pi$ being a streographic projection) seems much more plausible because the question is clearly sensible then. If Marge would give more context you could probably write an answer under that assumption.

Comment: and no matter what the topic is, [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX3VmDgiFnY) always helps on LFTs. :)

Comment: Yes S is the Riemann Sphere and $\pi$ is the sterographic projection. I am sorry I did not state this. I am new to this site. I thank you all for you suggestions. I just need to understand them. Because I do not at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I base my answer on the guess that $\pi$ is the stereographic projection from the Riemann sphere $S$ to the extended complex plane $\mathbf{C}\cup\{\infty\}$. I'm assuming that the equator of the sphere is on the complex plane. Align the 3-axes as follows: let the $x$-axis coincide with the real axis, $y$-axis with the imaginary axis, and $z$-axis stick out of the complex plane. I am further assuming that the exercise is about showing that a rotation about any of these 3 axes corresponds to a LFT of the complex plane. Here's a plan written in terms of extended hints:

Exercise #1: Check that a rotation about the $z$-axes yields an LFT. Well, 
this rotation by the angle $\phi$, call it $R(\phi)$ amounts to multiplication by $e^{i\phi}$.

Exercise #2: Let $\psi$ be a 90 degree rotation about the $y$-axis. In the 3D-coordinates this is $\psi(x,y,z)=(-z,y,x)$. Verify that the mapping $\pi\circ\psi\circ\pi^{-1}$ is a LFT.

Exercise #3: Show that an arbitrary rotation about the $x$-axis corresponds to a LFT. Hint: The LFTs form a group, right? What can you say about the 3D-mapping $\psi\circ R(\phi)\circ \psi^{-1}$?

Exercise #4: The same as in exercise #2, but this time we rotate about the $x$-axis, so instead of $\psi$ we look at $\tau(x,y,z)=(x,-z,y)$. Alternatively you can use a little bit of geometric thinking and combine ideas from exercises #1 and #3.

Exercise #5: The same as in exercise #4, but use $\tau$ instead of $\psi$ to show that an arbitrary rotation about the $y$-axis corresponds to a LFT.

If the question was only about those '2D' rotations then you are done. If you want to show the same for all the rotations of $S$ about an arbitrary axis, then I give you one more ...

Hint #6: Have you heard of Euler angles?

Comment: I apologize, if this was off the mark. Also I did my utmost to steer away from messy calculations involving the stereographic projection. Therefore I use a bit of geometric thinking (or matrix algebra, or conjugations in the group of rotations) to reduce to a few selected special cases, where the effect of the stereographic projection is hopefully easy to calculate. It really depends on your background, whether this is understandable.

Comment: Thanks, @anon. If only we could figure out what the question was.

Comment: @Jyrki, thanks for your answer. I do not really understand it at the moment. I am having difficulty understanding your exercise 2 and 3. Do you have any suggestions on how to understand it?

Comment: @Marge: Have you figured out a formula for the projection $\pi$ and its inverse? Perhaps you were given them? Anyway, presumably $\pi^{-1}(u+iv)=(x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$ for some functions $x,y,z$. In exercise #2 you should calculate $\pi(-z(u,v),y(u,v),x(u,v))=a(u,v)+i b(u,v)$ and then try to find a LFT $p$ such that $p(u+iv)=a(u,v)+i b(u,v)$.

Comment: @Marge I haven't done that calculation in ages, so I don't remember the answer. Anyway, the LFT of exercise #2 should map $i\mapsto i$, $1\mapsto \infty$ and $\infty\mapsto-1$, because the sphere is rotating about the imaginary axis. Check whether that LFT matches with the formula for $a(u,v)$ and $b(u,v)$ that you get.